# Filter a word in a image src with jquery

Tags: jquery, regex, string, filter

I am trying to filter for a specific word ("no-image") in my image src and if it returns true, I want to remove that particular image but keep the rest of the images.

This is my output:

```
<div class="product">
  <div class="image">
   <img src="mytee-red.jpg">
   <img src="mytee-blue.jpg">
   <img src="mytee-black.jpg">
   <img src="mytee-no-image.jpg">
 </div>
</div>
```

This is what I've tried so far but cant seem to get it working:

```
var keyword = "no-image";
 $(".product .image img").filter(function(index) {
    if ($(this).attr("src") == keyword) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

Any help would be great!!!

Comment: `==` checks if one string equals to another one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could simplify this into a single command -

```
$(".product .image img[src*='no-image']").remove();
```

The [jQuery attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) will help you pin-point the exact elements that you want containing the text "no-image" anywhere within the `src` attribute.

> This is the most generous of the jQuery attribute selectors that match
>   against a value. It will select an element if the selector's string
>   appears anywhere within the element's attribute value.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.product .image img[src*="no-image"]').remove();
```

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

No regex needed.

Answer (score 3):

according to your example, you need to use `match()` instead of `==`

```
var keyword = "no-image";
 $(".product .image img").filter(function(index) {
    if ($(this).attr("src").match(keyword)) {
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

Assuming that you want to remove `<img src="mytee-no-image.jpg">` as it matches the keyword `no-image`

Answer (score 3):

Other answers suggest better approaches, but a demonstration of `filter()` could be:

```
var keyword = "no-image";
 $(".product .image img").filter(function(index) {
    return $(this).attr("src").match(keyword);
}).remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter will only keep the items where the passed function returns true. Instead of trying to remove them inside the filter function, just return false.

> .filter( function(index) ): Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

```
var keyword = "no-image";
 $(".product .image img").filter(function(index) {
    return $(this).attr("src") != keyword;
});
```

Comment: Filtering them alone won't be enough to remove them (also the keyword supplied is not an exact match, so should search within content).